# Can I ask about alternatives to Photoshop?

Tags: discussion

I'm totally new to Photo.SE so I thought I'd ask first.

I am looking for more affordable alternatives to Photoshop that do a subset of its features (namely good CMYK handling).

Is this (fleshed out some more) a fair question to ask here?

Answer (score 8):

I would say it's a valid question, especially if the required feature-subset is included in the question.

Comment: +1 as long as at least some of the features you're looking for  are remotely connected to photo processing.

Answer (score -4):

The only inexpensive alternative to Photoshop (I believe you mean Adobe Creative Suite) is Corel Paint Shop Pro X2.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do there are lots of options.

Comment: -1 because this question is not "what are alternatives to PS"; it's asking whether that question is acceptable.